# Problem deleting by index in mongodb, Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to delete by index an item (that is an object) from an array. I achieve this in others situations but in this case it throw me that error. What I'm doing wrong?

## Schema

```
const activated =  Schema({
user:{type:String},
ts:{type:Date}
},{_id:false});

const pendientes = Schema({
testID:{type:Schema.ObjectId,ref:'test'},
enviadoPor:{type:String},
fechaEnvio:{type:Date,default:Date.now},

},{_id:false});

const realizados = Schema({
testID:{type:Schema.ObjectId,ref:'test'},
enviadoPor:{type:String},
fechaEnvio:{type:Date},
respuestas:{type:Schema.ObjectId,ref:'respuesta'},
fechaRealizacion:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
},{_id:false});


const pacienteSchema = Schema({
_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true },
pName: { type: String },
pEmail: { type: String, unique: true },
pPassword: { type: String, default: 'Cambiame' },
pCodigo: { type: String },
pTestRealizados: { type: [realizados] },
pTestPendientes: { type: [pendientes] },
pMedicos:{type:[Schema.ObjectId],ref:'user'},
pRespuestas:{type:[Schema.ObjectId],ref:'respuesta'},
pFechaRegistro: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
pActivated:{type:activated}

}, { versionKey: false });
```

## Function

```
exports.updatePTest = function (req, res) {
let pEmail = req.body.pEmail;
let tIndex = req.body.tIndex; // index that come from frontend
let parsedIndex = Number.parseInt(tIndex); // need to parse it to number
let pTestPendientes = `pTestPendientes.${tIndex}`; // Complete string with index (specific field)
let respuestaId = req.body.respuestaId;

Paciente.findOne({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
    'pTestPendientes': 1
}).then(result => {
    let i = parsedIndex;
    let item = result.pTestPendientes[i];
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
        '$push': {
            'pTestRealizados': {
                'testID': item.testID,
                'enviadoPor': item.enviadoPor,
                'fechaEnvio': item.fechaEnvio,
                'respuestas': respuestaId,
            },
            'pRespuestas': respuestaId
        }
    },{new:true}).exec().then(()=>{
        Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
            '$unset': {
                [pTestPendientes]: 1
            }
        }).then(()=>{                
           Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
                '$pull': {
                    'pTestPendientes': null
                }
            }).then(()=>{console.log('This then is not executed');}
            ).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); });
        }).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); });
    }).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); }); 
}).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); });
};
```

With this function, mongodb unset the item that I want (set it to null) but it dont execute the last part of the function ($pull) to delete nulls.
Some tips? Some ideas?
Thanks

## Update

Well thanks to @OTZ, the comment he post help me to do what I want BUT in this had a huge side effect. Now, my application dont recognize the document updated.

```
exports.updatePTest = function (req, res) {
let pEmail = req.body.pEmail;
let tIndex = req.body.tIndex;
let parsedIndex = Number.parseInt(tIndex);
let pTestPendientes = `pTestPendientes.${tIndex}`;
let respuestaId = req.body.respuestaId;

Paciente.findOne({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
    'pTestPendientes': 1
}).then(result => {
    let i = parsedIndex;
    let item = result.pTestPendientes[i];
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({ pEmail: pEmail }, {
        '$push': {
            'pTestRealizados': {
                'testID': item.testID,
                'enviadoPor': item.enviadoPor,
                'fechaEnvio': item.fechaEnvio,
                'respuestas': respuestaId,
            },
            'pRespuestas': respuestaId
        }
    },{new:true}).exec().then(()=>{ //New code thx to @OTZ
       Paciente.findOne({pEmail:pEmail}).then(paciente=>{paciente._doc.pTestPendientes.splice(tIndex,1); 
        paciente.save().then(()=>{console.log('saved');
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);})}).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); }); 
    }).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); }); 
}).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePTest', message: 'Error ' }); logger.error(err); });
};
```

Have the `paciente.save()` a different behavior or change something from my model? Someone who can explain this? In mongo Compass the document appear exactly how it need to appear, but is like some inside the model what I dont see is wrong or dissapear. I enter the correct password and email in my login page, and it return me a 401 and I know the pass and email is okay.

Some hint? Thank you.

## Update 2 [SOLVED] [EXPLANATION]

Ookay finally it works! I had a  `pacienteSchema.pre('save')` function in my Paciente Schema. So when I execute the save function that @OTZ post, I was doing a new encryptation of the password. I solved like this:

```
pacienteSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
if (this.isModified('pPassword')===false) {
    next();
}else{
    this.pPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(this.pPassword, saltRounds);
    next();
}
  });
```

Comment: You can try with `'$unset': {"pTestPendientes": 1}`

Comment: Cant do that because pTestPendientes is an array of objects, that will unset all the db, and I only want to delete the index that come from frontend.

Comment: Where is that index in your code?

Comment: Check code of function, I put some comments there. I unset correctly the item what I want but in the $pull, throw me the error.

Comment: What is the error that gets thrown for the $pull update operation?

Comment: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: How about you do an update by replacement? Find the document, do the update in your application code and replace what used to exist. Something like this: `Paciente.findOne({ pEmail: pEmail }).then(paciente => {
    paciente._doc.pTestPendientes.splice(tIndex, 1);
    paciente.save().then(() => console.log('saved')).catch((err) => {})
  })`.
That should take care of both the $unset and $pull operation.

Comment: This solved my problem. BUT, doing this is like the document was destroyed, because now I cant login with the credentials of the user, nothing change in the database only the thing what I want to change, but now document dont work with the application. Can you explain what is the behavior of ._doc or if save change something of mongoose schema?